# What does WDC stand for?

Tags: feature-management

It's a feature for badges and thankyous that can be awarded to internal users.

There is lots of documentation on what it does and how to use it, but I am having the most difficult time finding the meaning of the acronym.

Possibly "Workplace Development Center", but I have not seen that in any SF documentation, just a guess based on what I found on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WDC stands for "work dot com" (work.com)--similar to how KFC used to mean "Kentucky Fried Chicken" before they rebranded--which occurred as a result of a rebranding (see [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workcom_overview.htm&type=5)):

> NOTE On May 1, 2020, we rebranded this suite. It's now called WDC. If you're looking for information about our Work.com solution in response to the COVID-19 crisis, see [Return to the Workplace with Work.com](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workdotcom.htm&type=5&language=en_US).